# CakePHP 4 How to assign date field created_at to created

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I have a table called products. In product table I have 2 fields `created_at` and `update_at`. I don't want to change it to `created` and `modified`.

Without change table fields name, how can I assign that created_at field is created to get cakephp time helper auto update date ?

My entity I have tried below

```
protected $_accessible = [
        'created_at' => $this->created,
        'updated_at' => $this->modified,
];
```

Getting error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the manual. https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/behaviors/timestamp.html#basic-usage

> If you need to modify fields with different names, or want to update additional timestamp fields on custom events you can use some additional configuration:

```
class OrdersTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp', [
            'events' => [
                'Model.beforeSave' => [
                    'created_at' => 'new',
                    'updated_at' => 'always',
                ],
                'Orders.completed' => [
                    'completed_at' => 'always'
                ]
            ]
        ]);
    }
}
```